# How to create this into Wordpress shortcode with ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

Most the of fields I used are coming from ACF pro plugin and some of them are using the repeater of ACF, I am not good in PHP, how can I turn this code below into shortcode?

```
<div class="row">

    <?php 
        if( have_rows('our_golf_tours_list',161) ):                   
    ?>            
    <?php 
         while( have_rows('our_golf_tours_list',161) ): the_row();                   
    ?>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 m-b-30 col-package">
        <div class="packages-box">
            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('title_link'); ?>"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" alt="img"></a>
            <div class="package-details-2">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_sub_field('title_link'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></a></h3>
                <p><?php the_sub_field('date'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="packages-box-bottom">
            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('book_now_url'); ?>" class="btn btn-default-custom book-now-small <?php the_sub_field('hubspot_class'); ?>">Book Now <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('itinearay_url'); ?>" class="btn itinerary-blank">Itinerary </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Does this code below is close to correct? Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
function repeater_ad () { 

echo '<div class="row">

    <?php 
        if( have_rows('our_golf_tours_list',161) ):                   
    ?>            
    <?php 
         while( have_rows('our_golf_tours_list',161) ): the_row();                   
    ?>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 m-b-30 col-package">
        <div class="packages-box">
            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('title_link'); ?>"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" alt="img"></a>
            <div class="package-details-2">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_sub_field('title_link'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></a></h3>
                <p><?php the_sub_field('date'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="packages-box-bottom">
            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('book_now_url'); ?>" class="btn btn-default-custom book-now-small <?php the_sub_field('hubspot_class'); ?>">Book Now <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('itinearay_url'); ?>" class="btn itinerary-blank">Itinerary </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>';
add_shortcode('sss', 'repeater_ad');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your shortcode has a few problems:

**A. The function needs to be closed properly:**

```
function {

    // your code

} // <-- You forgot the closing bracket
```

**B. You should use a return statement instead of echo:**

You're using `echo` within the function, which isn't the safest thing to do as it doesn't guarantee that your content will render where you think.

It's best to encapsulate everything into a return statement that finishes the function.

Roughly, something like:

```
function {

    // Build up content and hold it somewhere (i.e. a variable)

    $content = '<h1>Fruits</h1>';

    $content .= '<div>apples</div>';
    $content .= '<div>oranges</div>';

    // When ready, finish the function and output the content to wherever the function was called (ie the shortcode)

    return $content;

}
```

**C. You're mixing HTML and PHP together improperly:**

In your original echo statement you're trying to cram all HTML and PHP together, however there needs to be a distinction between the two (ie open, close).

There's numerous ways & opinions on mixing PHP and HTML, and what you do depends on how you build your function logic. Anyways, as a starting point, here is how you'd mix HTML and PHP:

```
    $newContent = "pears";
    $content .= '<div>' . $pears . '</div>';
```

Plenty of tutorials and articles on this.

Comment: Thank you @MarsAndBack. I tried that but still not work. Maybe I just dont know which lines to put php variable. Appreciated more if you can write the exact code? Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry, I have to go work =). All I can suggest is start with a working shortcode, and slowly add ACF logic, testing along the way. This way you can narrow your problems down rather than trying to understand what could be a storm of issues.